# Make an electronic Stethoscope

Tags: sensor, medical

I've seen some kind of electronic stethoscope that can capture heart beat rate and filter it with so many other features.

Main oscope of my questoin is about capturing heart sound. There is many ways to detect muscle activities in body. But what is the best way to capture the sound of heart pumping ?

Which kind of sensors are commericaly used ?

PS:A well known commerical kind of what I mentioned is here : [thinklabs.com](http://www.thinklabs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

According to a project in University of Victoria , they use a Microphone with a chamber of silicon .

Here is the main Source : [iHeart Project](http://web.uvic.ca/~iheart/iHeart/Home.html)

But it seems a very odd way to capture sound of muscels using an acoustic microphone. It's exactly same as non-electronic stethoscopes, and main LNA is a commonly two stage amplifier with inbuilt filters.

What I've seen in recent commericaly stethoscopes is far away this way. They're using more advanced ways to capture its signal than using an acoustic Mic.

Comment: I am not aware of methods to capture sounds other than microphones. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mkeith I can mention piezo electric and surface contanting electrodes(bipolar) that attach to skin.

Comment: Maybe you have a more narrow definition of microphone than I do.